# What does "yields" mean in the phrase *yields no back edges* in DFS?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, depth-first-search

What does *yields* mean in the phrase *yields no back edges* in the context of DFS?

```
procedure DFS(G, v) is
    label v as discovered
    for all directed edges from v to w that are in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
        if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
            recursively call DFS(G, w)
```

As you see, the line *if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then* makes DFS never run back to a node that has already been labeled. So what does *yields no back edges* mean? Because I think that DFS never touches labeled nodes.

Comment: A *back edge* is an edge going from a vertex $v_2$ to another vertex $v_1$ such that $v_1$ was discovered by the algorithm before $v_2$. The phrase you are asking about is saying that such edges wouldn't be considered by the algorithm. The reason is that it only uses edges that go to vertices that hasn't been discovered yet.

Comment: thank you @plop                                                               .